# How to sum 3rd column for uniq IP and display the result using python?

Tags: python

file.txt contains following data:

```
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2 4678  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2 9879  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2 4678  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.3 4897  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2 4678  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.3 46756  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2 4678  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2 9879    
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2 4678  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.4 4897  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2 4678  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.3 46756    
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.4 4678  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2 9879  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2 4678  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.3 4897  
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2 4678    
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.3 46756
```

I want to find unique IP from second column and sum of all data from 3rd column.

Output should be like:

```
192.168.10.2 6789874 (6789874  is sum of all third column of repeated IP )  
192.168.10.3 6789875 (6789875  is sum of all third column of repeated IP )  
192.168.10.4 6789873 ( 6789873 is sum of all third column of repeated IP )
```

Comment: Please post the exact bit of code you're having difficulty with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pandas` and `NumPy` are great for these kind of things.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ', index_col=[0, 1], names=['val'])
print(df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(np.sum))
```

yields

```
                              val
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2   67061
             192.168.10.3  150062
             192.168.10.4    9575
```

Comment: Hi Alex Thanks! How to write in a file instead of printing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [collections defaultdict object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
 from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
with open("C:/a.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.strip().split()
        d[l[1]] += int(l[2])
```

Which returns:

```
[('192.168.10.4', 9575), ('192.168.10.2', 67061), ('192.168.10.3', 150062)]
```

Comment: Yours is better i always forgot using `int` for `defaultdict` ! ;)

Comment: Cool, I know, it happens to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. one of which is as follow.

```
counts = {}
with open('data.txt') as data:
    for line in data.readlines():
        first_col, second_col, third_col = line.split()
        if second_col in counts:
            counts[second_col] += int(third_col)
        else:
            counts[second_col] = int(third_col)
for key, value in counts.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

Output:

```
192.168.10.4 9575
192.168.10.2 67061
192.168.10.3 150062
```